# Getting siunitx and changes package to work together

Tags: siunitx, changes

I have received corrections on my thesis which I am trying to highlight using the Changes package.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}
   \deleted{ Test text Test text Test text \SI{45}{\percent} T
   est text Test text Test text Test text  \SI{1.65}{\kilogram} 
   Test text Test text Test text  \SI{9.57}{\percent} 
   (\si{\metre\per\metre}), 
   Test text Test text Test text  $\sim$\SI{17.1}{\gram} 
   Test text Test text  \SI{17}{\gram} Test text.}
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
! Extra}, or forgotten \endgroup. \UL@stop ...z@\else \UL@putbox \fi\else \egroup\egroup \UL@putbox \fi\if... ...est text \SI{17}{\gram\coeq} Test text .}
```

What I know:

1. I have perused every line, and all brackets are accounted for.
2. Once I remove the SI units, everything works. That's how I know that the siunitx package is involved.
3. Once I put `\mbox{}` around the text, it renders, but they all appear as one long line going into the margin.

My setup:

- pdfLaTeX
- Linux Mint 20.2 x64_86
- TeXMaker 5.0.3  as my frontend.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: From a chemist's point of view CO2 equivalents is NOT a unit,  but a qualfier to the unit (which is gram). You can define this as follows: `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} \DeclareSIQualifier{\coeq}{\ce{CO2}\textit{eq.}}`. The best thing is: you will not have to change anything in your code.